# turning off HTTPclient logger when log4j.xml can't be located

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am using HttpClient from Sesame framework. the client dumps quite a bit data in the console when I don't want it to. after researching, I see that I need to turn off in log4j.xml file, however, i couldn't find that file. The only files I have are apache ".jar" files, if that's the case, where can I turn off the logger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a log4j.xml or log4j.properties file on your classpath then you should use that one. If you do not have one, then create one on your classpath (or in your WEB-INF/classes in case of a webapp)